# CodeIgniter CSS files

Tags: css, codeigniter

I have a designer who makes the design for me and I want to start with CodeIgniter.

But the problem is to place the CSS and images file. I can put them in the root of the application but it is not supported in IDE (DW).

What I mean is the path is not working in DW to show CSS styling in live view and my designer can't make change without seeing styling.

I would also like to enable the intellisense feature on DW if possible.

Any help will be helful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't rely on DW. The quickest thing you can do is to render him a HTML page which he can open and edit and DW, and then just copy the CSS changes to your CI project.

Comment: Though I can use url to point to my css file. <?=base_url() ?> will not work in DW.

But what if I want to change the url of the site.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What I suggested is to make HTML template pages (save as... from browser, for example) and let the designer work on them. In the meanwhile, the developer works normally on the code (without changing the core structure of the views in order to avoid mismatching with the templates) and after that you just use the designer's new CSS file.

Answer (score 3):

I always save CSS files in the root directory. That way, I can quickly access them using the shortest of paths inside CI's URL helper functions.

Such as...

```
echo site_url('css/style.css');
```

Comment: It sure doesn't look like the root directory, nor does it matter if you use `site_url` or `base_url`...